# Create ASP.NET Profile

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm a sysadmin and I have to be able to create users. I wanna create a user and initialize its profile. How can I do this? I don't see any method in the ProfileProvider class for achieving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay appears like I have to create a class derived from the ProfileBase class and add the required properties. After that to create a profile I gotta call the Create static method in ProfileBase and cast it to my derived class.

After the profile changes have been made I just gotta call my derived profile class instance Save() method.

Comment: How to do it without ProfileBase.Create? (let's say, I wanna use non-default, my second profile provider, and can't point it in the web.config)

Answer (score 1):

To create a user use Membership.CreateUser().

To set a profile property in code use Profile.[propertyName] = [value].

[How profiles work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)

To edit another users profile use:

```
var profile = DefaultProfile.Create("UserName");
profile.[propertyName] = [value];
profile.Save();
```

Comment: I know how profiles work for the currently logged user. I wanna know how to set properties for OTHER users, not mine.